# ImapIdleChannelAdapter task-scheduler threads configuration

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I've been playing with the ImapIdleChannelAdapter integrated with Spring for a few.. and noticed that it starts 10 task-scheduler threads.

Mostly I have been checking the documentation for the ImapIdleChannelAdapter, but was not able to find a way to config how many threads it will start when listening to a email inbox.

Here is my Spring config:

```
<int:channel id="receiveChannel" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="threadPool" />
</int:channel>
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
    store-uri="imaps://#{systemProperties['imaps.encoded.username']}:#{systemProperties['imaps.encoded.password']}@#{systemProperties['imaps.host']}:#{systemProperties['imaps.port']}/INBOX"
    channel="receiveChannel" auto-startup="true" should-delete-messages="false" should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
</int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

by setting the number of threads in your executor -- it's the configuration of your "threadPool" bean not, of the imapAdapter itself -- though you can further configure the threading of the imapAdapter with setSendingTaskExecutor() and setTaskScheduler().

Comment: Im not sure what you are referring... but there are two pools being created now by this configuration a pool of thread schedulers and a pool of executors made by the "threadPool" bean defined in that xml.

"setTaskScheduler" sounds like appropriate but would be great if you can point me to documentation on where that can be done via the XML.

Thanks. I'll be also checking on that.